# Get response from img request

Tags: jquery, error-handling, image

How do I get hold of the response from a (non-ajax) image request.

Using jQuery I'm doing:

```
$('#myimg').error(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

However this err object doesnt have the response sent from the server. I can view the error response in chrome dev tools.. and it is the expected response for this error, but how do I access that message from javascript/jquery?

Comment: Are you doing a ajax request for this?

Comment: are you posting request to server by using ajax request

Comment: No. It's a direct request using src attribute.

Comment: Is there a particular part of the response that you were looking for?

Comment: Umm.. the body I guess. In my server i'm sending back a json object such as `{"error":"img not found"} .. I just want to grab that piece of json in the browser..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont think there is a way to do that
what you can do instead is make an ajax call when ever error event is raised

```
$('img').error(function(err){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $.ajax(src,[settings]);
})
$('img')[0].src = "http://asdasdasd.com"​;​​​​​
```

and you will get the response in the error handler of the `ajax` call

Comment: yeh ok.. thats quite nasty as would require 2 requests just to get the response.. I thought this would be simple but clearly not! Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the HTTP response I don´t think you will be able to get that through Javascript. Explain what you are trying to achieve and there might be other solutions that suits your needs.

I created a [small demo](http://jsfiddle.net/st3fan/RtX4G/) using the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) and [error](http://api.jquery.com/error/) events.

**Javascript**

```
$('img').load(function(e) {
    // Image loaded
    console.log(e.type, e);
})
.error(function(e) {
    // Failed to load image
    console.log(e.type, e);
    $(this).addClass('error');
    // NOTE: You could also change the src attribute.
});​
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/g/200/200') no-repeat;
}
.error { border: 2px dashed red; }​
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="img1" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
<img id="img2" src="http://placekitten.com/no/such/file" />​
```